# How to remove index.php from URL

Tags: yii

My yii application was installed in virtual host(http://yii.loc) (WAMP).
I need to remove index.php from url. But only http://yii.loc url works, the other pages says "Not Found".

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/',
        '<controller:\w+>/ <action:\w+>' => '/',
),
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the settings of Apache. I had same problems when the rewrite rule was disabled.

Go to WAMP icon->Apache modules->rewrite_module   and turn it on

Than try to restart your WAMP & aplication in browser)

Comment: AllowOverride must also be enabled in the site configuration

Comment: rewrite_module is enabled, AllowOverride too, but get the result "Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution. By mistake I have changed the .htaccess which are located in protected folder. So I restored the file

```
deny from all
```

The I created a new .htaccess file in the root directroy and add

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And now it works.